# Swift 3 - No member error after instantiating view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

When I instantiate a view controller and try to access one of its variables, I get a: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'someObjectVar'`

Here is my code:

```
let testVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testVC") as UIViewController

testVC.someObjectVar = someObject // error is here

self.present(testVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The variable in `testVC` is:

```
var someObjectVar : someObjectType!
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678991/uiviewcontroller-has-no-member-error-when-im-using-instantiateviewcontrollerwit) which has the same issue as me but the solution doesn't work for me since I am not doing the same thing...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You actually are doing the same thing as the asker in the question you linked, the solution they suggest in the comments doesn't actually make sense though since you need to change your `as UIViewController` to `as! [Actual Class of testVC]` rather than just removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting it to UIViewController which most definitely does not have that property on it.  You need to cast it as whatever UIViewController subclass you made that has that property associated with it.

Comment: Oh my goodness.  What a bone-headed mistake!  Thank you so much for pointing that out for me.